# How to edit order summary field labels on paypal page

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

My company sells online services and I have been able to limit my customers to buy one service at a time with the help of rules. However, when my users are directed to paypal, following information is presented to them on the paypal site:

[image: Screen shot]

Is there a way I can edit paypal label ‘item price’, as can be seen in the above shot, to something else such as ‘service charges’. Also can I remove the quantity field all together, as my users are unable to purchase more than one service at a time. No point to show the quantity to them.

I am using following code to remove quantity field, but it still appears on paypal. Also, I am unable to find the field label: item price in this hook.

```
function checkout_forms_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter(&$data, $order) {
unset($data['on0_1']);  //to remove options
unset($data['os0_1']);  // to remove quantity field
}
```

Comment: Paypal's docs don't indicate that's possible, no: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/. "Item price" is _their_ label, it doesn't come from Drupal (which is why you can't find it to change it). There's nothing to suggest the quantity field can be removed either.

Comment: Thanks Clive. I didnt know that .. u saved me a lot of time from debugging it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Paypal WPS API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA) can be used to hold multiple individual items, but it can also just be used to handle a single order. It effectively does this by making the Drupal order the only product on the PayPal order.

If you are wanting to customize checkout further, you'll need to find another processor that gives you that ability. PayPal PayFlow Pro or some other option might work.